# Encoded HTML Tags in Query String still causing 500 Error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, url, query-string

Hoping this is a quick fix.

I'm sending a query string from an AngularJS application to a web API coded in C#. The string contains a "message" value which may or may not contain url-encoded HTML tags.

Here's a basic example:

```
msg = "<a>"
querystring = "/SERVERPATH/?id=1&msg=%3Ca%3E"
```

Sending the string above to my API results in a 500 Error and the "msg" value never actually reaches the server. On the other hand, adding a space before and after the "a" causes everything to work great.

```
msg = "< a >"
querystring = "/SERVERPATH/?id=1&msg=%3C%20a%20%3E"
```

Is there a special type of validation occurring that I don't know about, and is there a way to configure these rules myself?

This is probably web.config related, but I could be totally wrong about that. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I remember, ASP.NET doesn't allow you to submit HTML to the server by default. I'm pretty sure there's a setting for this in web.config though - http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

Comment: You can send message in post body using HTTP POST method instead of query string.

Comment: I actually am using POST in conjunction with AngularJS's $http method. The message is added as a parameter, then gets formatted and encoded into a query string after it's submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 500 is for internal server error. It means your code do reach your web service. By your example (where on putting a space before and after 'a' makes everything work) I am pretty sure that request validation is failing at your web service. To understand request validation please visit [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

A word of caution: Try not to disable request validation on your web service. Doing that poses a huge security threat.

You may consider a work around, where instead of using URLEncode you can use HTMLEncode for encoding the query string values (values only).